# Change datasource property using org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode

Tags: java, wildfly, datasource, jboss-cli

I have quite regular data source definition in standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MYDS" pool-name="MYDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:MYDB</connection-url>
            <security>
                <user-name>superman</user-name>
            </security>
        </datasource>
   </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

Try to change some property from command-line and this works fine:

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=MYDS:write-attribute(name=connection-url,value=achooo)
```

result:

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
```

But using ModelNode API, it gets me crazy.

```
ModelNode request = new ModelNode();
request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("subsystem", "datasources");
request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("data-source", "MYDS");
request.get(ClientConstants.OP).set(ClientConstants.WRITE_ATTRIBUTE_OPERATION);
request.get("connection-url").set("achooo");
myCliExecutor.executeCliCommandWithResult(request);
```

result:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS014746: name may not be null",
    "rolled-back" => true,
    "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
}
```

Comment: What version of WildFly? The DMR is not quite right, but there are some helper methods available that you could take advantage of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're DMR is not quite correct. For the `write-attribute` operation you need to define a `name` and `value` attribute. It should look something more like:

```java
final ModelNode address = new ModelNode().setEmptyList();
address.add("subsystem", "datasources");
address.add("data-source", "ExampleDS");

ModelNode request = new ModelNode();
request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).set(address);
request.get(ClientConstants.OP).set(ClientConstants.WRITE_ATTRIBUTE_OPERATION);
request.get("name").set("connection-url");
request.get("value").set("achooo");
myCliExecutor.executeCliCommandWithResult(request);
```

In the `org.wildfly.core:controller-client` there is also an `Operations` helper which should help.

```java
final ModelNode address = Operations.createAddress("subsystem", "datasources", "data-source", "MYDS");
final ModelNod op = Operations.createWriteAttributeOperation(address, "connection-url", "achooo");
myCliExecutor.executeCliCommandWithResult(op);
```

Comment: Unfortunately on line `writeOp.get("name").set("connection-url");` I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException because writeOp object has only `protected = false` and `value = "write-attribute"`. I dont have such API like Operations.createAddress, maybe because I use Wildfly 8.2

Comment: Ah yeah sorry. The `createAddress()` wasn't introduced until later. I think the `Operations.createWriteAttributeOperation()` should exist. I'll edit and fix the longer example though. It is incorrect my apologies for that.